# None of or None for

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-meaning, verb-agreement, correspondence

**1. There is none of you.
2. There is none fore you.**

Both these two sentences have no context. Students are asked in an examination to choose the correct one.

Comment: (2) is grammatically correct (except that it should be **for**). (1) is not. **You** must refer to people, something countable, so it should be **there are none**.

Comment: @KateBunting *None* taking a singular or plural form has its subtleties, but to me in OP's case both forms are valid, and generally *none* with countable nouns can take both. Cf. *None of my shirts fit/fits me anymore*